# Why I can't create object instance?

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

I need add objects to list, but I can't understand how to do it correctly.
Every new object I get from console.
How to fix it?

My try:

```
namespace ExampleCars
{
    public class Car
    {
        public string name;
        public int speed;
        public Car(string name, int speed)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.speed = speed;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name;
            int speed, elements;
            List<Object> cars = new List<Object>();

            elements = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (elements > 0)
            {                
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {                    
                    name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());                    
                    speed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());                    
                    Car newCar = new Car(name, speed);
                    cars.Add(newCar);
                }
            }

            foreach (var oneCar in cars)
                Console.WriteLine(oneCar);
        }
    }
}
```

In console I get this (`elements == 1`):

```
ExampleCars.Car
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it would be better to create a `List` of `Cars`, instead of list of `Objects`. So change this:

```
List<Object> cars = new List<Object>();
```

To this:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
```

Also it would be great, if you use properties instead of fields. And finally as the solution for your question, and based on what you need to show in your last `Console.Writeline` method, you can override the [`ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) method. Your class should be something like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public Car(string name, int speed)
    {
        Name = name;
        Speed = speed;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name = {Name}, Speed = {Speed} ";
    }
}
```

And if you are using the older versions of C#:

```
return String.Format("Name = {0}, Speed = {1}", Name, Speed);
```

The `$` is called String Interpolation and is available from C#6+. I have provided an equivalent of it using `String.Format` that is available in older versions of C#.

Comment: In this code problems with return $"Name = {Name}, Speed = {Speed} ";

VS doesn't understand symbol $ and write, that need ";"

Comment: @Jack OK. It is called String Interpolation and is available from C#6+. Check my updated answer, I have provided an equivalent of it, that is available in older versions of C#.

Answer (score 1):

when you write your Car object in the console, Car.ToString method call in background.

> Object.ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework.
>   It converts an object to its string representation so that it is
>   suitable for display. Default implementations of the Object.ToString
>   method return the fully qualified name of the object's type.

[Object.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)

if you want to change default string presentation of your object, you have to override the method.

```
   public class Car
    {
        public string name;
        public int speed;
        public Car(string name, int speed)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{name} {speed}";

        }
    }
```

Comment: In this code problems with return $"{name} {speed}";
VS doesn't understand symbol $ and write, that need ";"

Comment: i can't understand your point.I have tested it and it's working

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine, is responsible of printing text.

In case of `Console.WriteLine(string)` is actually returns the string value;
In **any other case**, it tries to convert the value into a string by **invoking the instance object** `.ToString()` method.

Any type in C# inherits from System.Object, and thus, it has the [.ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) method.
By using Inheritance, many types override the actual inherited method and implement their perception of what their value should look like as a string.

This can be easily done, by using [method overriding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) and apply your own logic.

Example taken from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
    }
}
```

Test code

```
Person person = new Person { Name = "John", Age = 12 };
Console.WriteLine(person);
// Output:
// Person: John 12
```

So you may ask, why do i get `ExampleCars.Car` ? you're getting it, because you didn't implement your own representation of the object .ToString method. Thus, the System.Object implementation is to actually return the instance type as string, which is exactly what you're getting.

System.Object.ToString() [Source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs).

```
public virtual String ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

`System.Int32` implement by changing the value of `1` to `"1"`
While other type can implement their own. e.g: `new DateTime(2018, 12, 31) can return "12/31/2018"`